# sudden error after removing app from iphone simulator on Xcode

Tags: xcode

my app was working perfectly fine, until I cleaned the targets and deleted the app from iphone simulator.
It now compiles but ends itself as soon as it runs, with NSInternalInconsistency exception.

Trying NSLog only tells me that the error comes from the main function, which I didn't touch.
I think the error has to do with the modal view, but it was running perfectly until I removed the app on iphone simulator. Only, I changed some of the image file names from Resources folder right before I cleaned the targets... (but even so, it was running well before cleaning/deleting).

Has anyone had this experience where everything that has worked suddenly gives you an error after cleaning/removing? How did you deal with this?

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Only, I changed some of the image file names from Resources folder right before I cleaned the targets... (but even so, it was running well before cleaning/deleting).

it was running well because the renamed images weren't changed in the app on the simulator.
Files aren't deleted from the app bundle when you install your app with Xcode.

Clean All doesn't remove them, neither does the deletion of the build directory. Unless the app is removed from the simulator the old files are still available for the simulator.

Find the places where the old images are still referenced in your project.

Comment: im not sure if I understand your answer... I did remove the app from the simulator, so old files shouldn't be available... in fact, the project started to not work since I deleted the app from simulator...